# Definite integral of the logarithm of a trigonometric polynomial

Tags: trigonometry, polynomials, definite-integrals, logarithms

Let $p$ and $q$ be two real numbers such that $q>p^2$, so that $1+2px+qx^2>0$ for all $x$. I need to calculate the integral
\begin{equation*}
\int_0^\pi\ln\big(1+2p\cos\theta+q\cos^2\theta\big)d\theta.
\end{equation*}
Any idea? Thank you!

I am able to calculate the integral in the case $q<1$. In fact, it is known that if $z\in\mathbb{C}$ satisfies $|z|<1$, then
\begin{equation*}
\int_0^\pi\ln\big(1+z\cos\theta\big)d\theta=\pi\ln\bigg(\frac{1+\sqrt{1-z^2}}{2}\bigg).
\end{equation*}
We have $1+2p\cos\theta+q\cos^2\theta=(1+z\cos\theta)(1+\bar{z}\cos\theta)$ for all $\theta$ with
\begin{equation*}
z:=p-\mathrm{i}\sqrt{q-p^2}.
\end{equation*}
The hypothesis $q<1$ gives $|z|=\sqrt{q}<1$. Thus,
\begin{align}
\nonumber
 \int_0^\pi\ln\big(1+2p\cos\theta+q\cos^2\theta\big)d\theta&=
\int_0^\pi\ln\big(1+z\cos\theta\big)d\theta+\int_0^\pi\ln\big(1+\bar{z}\cos\theta\big)d\theta\\
\nonumber
&=\pi\ln\bigg(\frac{1+\sqrt{1-z^2}}{2}\bigg)+\pi\ln\bigg(\frac{1+\sqrt{1-\bar{z}^2}}{2}\bigg)\\
&=2\pi\ln\bigg|\frac{1+\sqrt{1-z^2}}{2}\bigg|.
\end{align}
This result extends to $q=1$ by continuity. Numerical simulations suggest that this result is valid for all $q$. So, what I am actually searching for is a way to prove it for $q>1$.

Comment: What is the source of this problem?

Comment: Please add what you have tried, also I imagine it would have something to do with IBP or differentiating under the integral sign , as when you take the derivative of the integrand you end up with an expression involving a factor of $\sin(x)$.

Comment: I came across this problem while trying to calculate the determinant of a large block Toeplitz matrix.

Comment: use analytic continuation: if $z \notin \mathbb R -(-1,1)$ one has that $1+z\cos \theta \notin (-\infty,0]$ so $\log(1+z\cos \theta)$ is analytic in $z$ for a given $\theta$, hence its integral is, while clearly $\pi\ln\frac{1+\sqrt{1-z^2}}{2}$ is same since $\sqrt{1-z^2}$ defined to be $1$ for $z=0$ is analytic outside $\mathbb R -(-1,1)$ and not a negative number (real part is positive), so its logarithm is analytic, hence equality for $|z|<1$ implies equality everywhere

Comment: Thank you very much Conrad! I am not very familiar with analytic continuation and so I did not think of it. Now I am convinced that analytic continuation is the way to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

Letting $D$ denote the subset of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ specified by

$$D:=\{\left(p,q\right)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}\mid p^{2}<q\},$$

define the function $\mathcal{I}:D\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ via the logarithmic integral

$$\mathcal{I}{\left(p,q\right)}:=\int_{0}^{\pi}\mathrm{d}\theta\,\ln{\left(1+2p\cos{\left(\theta\right)}+q\cos^{2}{\left(\theta\right)}\right)}.$$

We will show ultimately that

$$\mathcal{I}{\left(p,q\right)}=2\pi\ln{\left(\frac{\sqrt{1+q-2p}+\sqrt{1+q+2p}+\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1-q+\sqrt{\left(1+q\right)^{2}-4p^{2}}}}{4}\right)}.$$

Without a doubt this is the **LOOONG** way to obtain the above expression, but there are no domain issues and we don't have to think about complex numbers or analytic continuation if we don't want to. Enjoy.

---

First off, we can show that $\mathcal{I}$ is even in its first argument. For any $\left(p,q\right)\in D$,

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}{\left(-p,q\right)}
&=\int_{0}^{\pi}\mathrm{d}\theta\,\ln{\left(1-2p\cos{\left(\theta\right)}+q\cos^{2}{\left(\theta\right)}\right)}\\
&=\int_{0}^{\pi}\mathrm{d}\theta\,\ln{\left(1-2p\cos{\left(\pi-\theta\right)}+q\cos^{2}{\left(\pi-\theta\right)}\right)};~~~\small{\left[\theta\mapsto\pi-\theta\right]}\\
&=\int_{0}^{\pi}\mathrm{d}\theta\,\ln{\left(1+2p\cos{\left(\theta\right)}+q\cos^{2}{\left(\theta\right)}\right)}\\
&=\mathcal{I}{\left(p,q\right)}.\\
\end{align}$$

---

Suppose $\left(p,q\right)\in D$. Then, $0<q$ and $-1<\frac{p}{\sqrt{q}}<1$, and so $0<\frac{\pi}{2}-\arcsin{\left(\frac{p}{\sqrt{q}}\right)}<\pi$.

Setting $\sqrt{q}=:r\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ and

$$\frac{\pi}{2}-\arcsin{\left(\frac{p}{\sqrt{q}}\right)}=:\alpha\in\left(0,\pi\right),$$

we then have $\cos{\left(\alpha\right)}=\frac{p}{\sqrt{q}}$, and we can rewrite the integral $\mathcal{I}$ as

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}{\left(p,q\right)}
&=\int_{0}^{\pi}\mathrm{d}\theta\,\ln{\left(1+2p\cos{\left(\theta\right)}+q\cos^{2}{\left(\theta\right)}\right)}\\
&=\int_{0}^{\pi}\mathrm{d}\theta\,\ln{\left(1-2p\cos{\left(\theta\right)}+q\cos^{2}{\left(\theta\right)}\right)};~~~\small{even\,symmetry}\\
&=\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\ln{\left(1-2p\cos{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\varphi\right)}+q\cos^{2}{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\varphi\right)}\right)};~~~\small{\left[\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}-\varphi\right]}\\
&=\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\ln{\left(1-2p\sin{\left(\varphi\right)}+q\sin^{2}{\left(\varphi\right)}\right)}\\
&=\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\ln{\left(1-2r\cos{\left(\alpha\right)}\sin{\left(\varphi\right)}+r^{2}\sin^{2}{\left(\varphi\right)}\right)}.\\
\end{align}$$

Then, applying the tangent half-angle substitution followed by an appropriate linear fractional transformation, we find

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}{\left(p,q\right)}
&=\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\ln{\left(1-2r\cos{\left(\alpha\right)}\sin{\left(\varphi\right)}+r^{2}\sin^{2}{\left(\varphi\right)}\right)}\\
&=\int_{-1}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{2}{1+t^{2}}\ln{\left(1-2r\cos{\left(\alpha\right)}\left(\frac{2t}{1+t^{2}}\right)+r^{2}\left(\frac{2t}{1+t^{2}}\right)^{2}\right)};~~~\small{\left[\varphi=2\arctan{\left(t\right)}\right]}\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2}{1+x^{2}}\ln{\left(1-2r\cos{\left(\alpha\right)}\left(\frac{1-x^{2}}{1+x^{2}}\right)+r^{2}\left(\frac{1-x^{2}}{1+x^{2}}\right)^{2}\right)};~~~\small{\left[t=\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right]}\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2}{1+x^{2}}\ln{\left(\frac{\left(1+x^{2}\right)^{2}-2r\cos{\left(\alpha\right)}\left(1-x^{4}\right)+r^{2}\left(1-x^{2}\right)^{2}}{\left(1+x^{2}\right)^{2}}\right)}\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2}{1+x^{2}}\ln{\left(\frac{\left[1-2r\cos{\left(\alpha\right)}+r^{2}\right]+2\left(1-r^{2}\right)x^{2}+\left[1+2r\cos{\left(\alpha\right)}+r^{2}\right]x^{4}}{\left(1+x^{2}\right)^{2}}\right)}.\\
\end{align}$$

---

Lemma: Given $(A,B,C)\in\mathbb{R}^{3}$ with $0<A\land0<C\land0<AC-B^{2}$, it can be shown algebraically that the biquadratic polynomial $A+2Bx^{2}+Cx^{4}$ can be factored into positive-definite quadratics with real coefficients as

$$A+2Bx^{2}+Cx^{4}=\left(\sqrt{A}+2\sqrt{\frac{-B+\sqrt{AC}}{2}}\,x+\sqrt{C}\,x^{2}\right)\left(\sqrt{A}-2\sqrt{\frac{-B+\sqrt{AC}}{2}}\,x+\sqrt{C}\,x^{2}\right).$$

In particular, if we take

$$\begin{align}
A&=1-2r\cos{\left(\alpha\right)}+r^{2}=\left[r-\cos{\left(\alpha\right)}\right]^{2}+\sin^{2}{\left(\alpha\right)},\\
B&=1-r^{2},\\
C&=1+2r\cos{\left(\alpha\right)}+r^{2}=\left[r+\cos{\left(\alpha\right)}\right]^{2}+\sin^{2}{\left(\alpha\right)},\\
\end{align}$$

then for $0<r\land0<\alpha<\pi$ we have $A>0\land C>0$ and

$$AC-B^{2}=4r^{2}\sin^{2}{\left(\alpha\right)}>0.$$

We then find

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}{\left(p,q\right)}
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2}{1+x^{2}}\ln{\left(\frac{\left[1-2r\cos{\left(\alpha\right)}+r^{2}\right]+2\left(1-r^{2}\right)x^{2}+\left[1+2r\cos{\left(\alpha\right)}+r^{2}\right]x^{4}}{\left(1+x^{2}\right)^{2}}\right)}\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2}{1+x^{2}}\ln{\left(\frac{A+2Bx^{2}+Cx^{4}}{\left(1+x^{2}\right)^{2}}\right)}\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2}{1+x^{2}}\ln{\left(\frac{\sqrt{A}+2\sqrt{\frac{-B+\sqrt{AC}}{2}}\,x+\sqrt{C}\,x^{2}}{1+x^{2}}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{A}-2\sqrt{\frac{-B+\sqrt{AC}}{2}}\,x+\sqrt{C}\,x^{2}}{1+x^{2}}\right)}\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2}{1+x^{2}}\ln{\left(\frac{\sqrt{A}+2\sqrt{\frac{-B+\sqrt{AC}}{2}}\,x+\sqrt{C}\,x^{2}}{1+x^{2}}\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2}{1+x^{2}}\ln{\left(\frac{\sqrt{A}-2\sqrt{\frac{-B+\sqrt{AC}}{2}}\,x+\sqrt{C}\,x^{2}}{1+x^{2}}\right)}\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2}{1+x^{2}}\ln{\left(\frac{\sqrt{A}+2\sqrt{\frac{-B+\sqrt{AC}}{2}}\,x+\sqrt{C}\,x^{2}}{1+x^{2}}\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\int_{-\infty}^{0}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2}{1+x^{2}}\ln{\left(\frac{\sqrt{A}+2\sqrt{\frac{-B+\sqrt{AC}}{2}}\,x+\sqrt{C}\,x^{2}}{1+x^{2}}\right)};~~~\small{\left[x\mapsto-x\right]}\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2}{1+x^{2}}\ln{\left(\frac{\sqrt{A}+2\sqrt{\frac{-B+\sqrt{AC}}{2}}\,x+\sqrt{C}\,x^{2}}{1+x^{2}}\right)},\\
\end{align}$$

which can be rearranged as

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}{\left(p,q\right)}
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2}{x^{2}+1}\ln{\left(\frac{\sqrt{C}\,x^{2}+2\sqrt{\frac{-B+\sqrt{AC}}{2}}\,x+\sqrt{A}}{x^{2}+1}\right)}\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2}{x^{2}+1}\ln{\left(\frac{\sqrt{C}\left[x^{2}+2\sqrt{\frac{-B+\sqrt{AC}}{2C}}\,x+\sqrt{\frac{A}{C}}\right]}{x^{2}+1}\right)}\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2}{x^{2}+1}\ln{\left(\sqrt{C}\right)}+\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2}{x^{2}+1}\ln{\left(\frac{x^{2}+2\sqrt{\frac{-B+\sqrt{AC}}{2C}}\,x+\sqrt{\frac{A}{C}}}{x^{2}+1}\right)}\\
&=\ln{\left(C\right)}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1}{x^{2}+1}\\
&~~~~~+\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2}{x^{2}+1}\ln{\left(\frac{x^{2}+2\sqrt{-\frac{B}{2C}+\frac12\sqrt{\frac{A}{C}}}\,x+\sqrt{\frac{A}{C}}}{x^{2}+1}\right)}\\
&=\pi\ln{\left(C\right)}+\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2}{x^{2}+1}\ln{\left(\frac{\left(x+\sqrt{\frac{-B+\sqrt{AC}}{2C}}\right)^{2}+\left(\sqrt{\frac{B+\sqrt{AC}}{2C}}\right)^{2}}{x^{2}+1}\right)}\\
&=\pi\ln{\left(C\right)}+\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2}{x^{2}+1}\ln{\left(\frac{\left(x+a\right)^{2}+b^{2}}{x^{2}+1}\right)},\\
\end{align}$$

where in the last line above we've set

$$a:=\sqrt{\frac{-B+\sqrt{AC}}{2C}}>0,$$

$$b:=\sqrt{\frac{B+\sqrt{AC}}{2C}}>0.$$

Evaluating the last integral using the integration formula (derived in the appendix below)

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2}{x^{2}+1}\ln{\left(\frac{\left(x+a\right)^{2}+b^{2}}{x^{2}+1}\right)}=2\pi\ln{\left(\frac{a^{2}+\left(b+1\right)^{2}}{4}\right)};~~~\small{a\in\mathbb{R}\land b\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}},$$

we finally arrive at an explicit closed-form expression for $\mathcal{I}$ in terms of elementary functions:

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}{\left(p,q\right)}
&=\pi\ln{\left(C\right)}+\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2}{x^{2}+1}\ln{\left(\frac{\left(x+a\right)^{2}+b^{2}}{x^{2}+1}\right)}\\
&=2\pi\ln{\left(\sqrt{C}\right)}+2\pi\ln{\left(\frac{a^{2}+\left(b+1\right)^{2}}{4}\right)}\\
&=2\pi\ln{\left(\sqrt{C}\right)}+2\pi\ln{\left(\frac{\sqrt{A}+\sqrt{2}\sqrt{B+\sqrt{AC}}+\sqrt{C}}{4\sqrt{C}}\right)}\\
&=2\pi\ln{\left(\frac{\sqrt{A}+\sqrt{C}+\sqrt{2}\sqrt{B+\sqrt{AC}}}{4}\right)}\\
&=2\pi\ln{\left(\frac{\sqrt{1+q-2p}+\sqrt{1+q+2p}+\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1-q+\sqrt{\left(1+q-2p\right)\left(1+q+2p\right)}}}{4}\right)}\\
&=2\pi\ln{\left(\frac{\sqrt{1+q-2p}+\sqrt{1+q+2p}+\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1-q+\sqrt{\left(1+q\right)^{2}-4p^{2}}}}{4}\right)}.\blacksquare\\
\end{align}$$

---

**Appendix:** Define the function $\mathcal{J}:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}_{>0}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ via the improper integral

$$\mathcal{J}{\left(a,b\right)}:=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2}{x^{2}+1}\ln{\left(\frac{\left(x+a\right)^{2}+b^{2}}{x^{2}+1}\right)}.$$

It's easy to show that $\mathcal{J}$ is even in the first variable, i.e.,

$$\forall\left(a,b\right)\in\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}_{>0}:\mathcal{J}{\left(a,b\right)}=\mathcal{J}{\left(-a,b\right)},$$

so without loss of generality we may assume $a\ge0$.

Suppose $\left(a,b\right)\in\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}_{>0}$, assume $a>0$. It follows from the fundamental theorem of calculus and the Leibniz integral rule for differentiation under the integral sign that

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{J}{\left(a,b\right)}
&=\mathcal{J}{\left(0,b\right)}+\int_{0}^{a}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\mathcal{J}{\left(y,b\right)}\\
&=\mathcal{J}{\left(0,b\right)}+\int_{0}^{a}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2}{x^{2}+1}\ln{\left(\frac{\left(x+y\right)^{2}+b^{2}}{x^{2}+1}\right)}\\
&=\mathcal{J}{\left(0,b\right)}+\int_{0}^{a}\mathrm{d}y\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2}{x^{2}+1}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\ln{\left(\frac{\left(x+y\right)^{2}+b^{2}}{x^{2}+1}\right)}\\
&=\mathcal{J}{\left(0,b\right)}+\int_{0}^{a}\mathrm{d}y\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{4\left(x+y\right)}{\left(x^{2}+1\right)\left[\left(x+y\right)^{2}+b^{2}\right]}\\
&=\mathcal{J}{\left(0,b\right)}+\int_{0}^{a}\mathrm{d}y\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1}{\left[y^{2}+\left(b+1\right)^{2}\right]\left[y^{2}+\left(b-1\right)^{2}\right]}\bigg{[}\frac{4y\left(y^{2}+b^{2}+1\right)}{x^{2}+1}\\
&~~~~~-\frac{8b^{2}y}{\left(x+y\right)^{2}+b^{2}}+\frac{4\left(y^{2}-b^{2}+1\right)\left(x+y\right)}{\left(x+y\right)^{2}+b^{2}}-\frac{4\left(y^{2}-b^{2}+1\right)x}{x^{2}+1}\bigg{]};~~~\small{P.F.D.}\\
&=\mathcal{J}{\left(0,b\right)}+\int_{0}^{a}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{2}{\left[y^{2}+\left(b+1\right)^{2}\right]\left[y^{2}+\left(b-1\right)^{2}\right]}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\bigg{[}\frac{2y\left(y^{2}+b^{2}+1\right)}{x^{2}+1}\\
&~~~~~-\frac{4y}{\left(\frac{x+y}{b}\right)^{2}+1}+\left(y^{2}-b^{2}+1\right)\left[\frac{2\left(x+y\right)}{\left(x+y\right)^{2}+b^{2}}-\frac{2x}{x^{2}+1}\right]\bigg{]}\\
&=\mathcal{J}{\left(0,b\right)}+\int_{0}^{a}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{2}{\left[y^{2}+\left(b+1\right)^{2}\right]\left[y^{2}+\left(b-1\right)^{2}\right]}\bigg{[}2y\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{y^{2}+b^{2}+1}{x^{2}+1}\\
&~~~~~-2y\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2}{\left(\frac{x+y}{b}\right)^{2}+1}+\left(y^{2}-b^{2}+1\right)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\left[\frac{2\left(x+y\right)}{\left(x+y\right)^{2}+b^{2}}-\frac{2x}{x^{2}+1}\right]\bigg{]}\\
&=\mathcal{J}{\left(0,b\right)}+\int_{0}^{a}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{2}{\left[y^{2}+\left(b+1\right)^{2}\right]\left[y^{2}+\left(b-1\right)^{2}\right]}\bigg{[}2y\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{y^{2}+b^{2}+1}{x^{2}+1}\\
&~~~~~-2y\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{2b}{t^{2}+1};~~~\small{\left[x=bt-y\right]}\\
&~~~~~+\left(y^{2}-b^{2}+1\right)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{d}{dx}\left[\ln{\left(\left(x+y\right)^{2}+b^{2}\right)}-\ln{\left(x^{2}+1\right)}\right]\bigg{]}\\
&=\mathcal{J}{\left(0,b\right)}+\int_{0}^{a}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{2}{\left[y^{2}+\left(b+1\right)^{2}\right]\left[y^{2}+\left(b-1\right)^{2}\right]}\bigg{[}2y\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{y^{2}+b^{2}-2b+1}{t^{2}+1}\\
&~~~~~+\left(y^{2}-b^{2}+1\right)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{d}{dx}\ln{\left(\frac{\left(x+y\right)^{2}+b^{2}}{x^{2}+1}\right)}\bigg{]}\\
&=\mathcal{J}{\left(0,b\right)}+2\int_{0}^{a}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{2y}{y^{2}+\left(b+1\right)^{2}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{1}{t^{2}+1}\\
&=\mathcal{J}{\left(0,b\right)}+2\pi\int_{0}^{a}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{d}{dy}\ln{\left(y^{2}+\left(b+1\right)^{2}\right)}\\
&=\mathcal{J}{\left(0,b\right)}+2\pi\left[\ln{\left(a^{2}+\left(b+1\right)^{2}\right)}-\ln{\left(\left(b+1\right)^{2}\right)}\right]\\
&=2\pi\left[\ln{\left(a^{2}+\left(b+1\right)^{2}\right)}-2\ln{\left(b+1\right)}\right]+\mathcal{J}{\left(0,b\right)},\\
\end{align}$$

where for $b>0$ we have

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{J}{\left(0,b\right)}
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2}{x^{2}+1}\ln{\left(\frac{x^{2}+b^{2}}{x^{2}+1}\right)}\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2}{x^{2}+1}\int_{1}^{b}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{2y}{x^{2}+y^{2}}\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\int_{1}^{b}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{2}{x^{2}+1}\cdot\frac{2y}{x^{2}+y^{2}}\\
&=\int_{1}^{b}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{4y}{y^{2}-1}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{y^{2}-1}{\left(x^{2}+1\right)\left(x^{2}+y^{2}\right)}\\
&=\int_{1}^{b}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{4y}{y^{2}-1}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\left[\frac{1}{x^{2}+1}-\frac{1}{x^{2}+y^{2}}\right]\\
&=\int_{1}^{b}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{4}{y^{2}-1}\left[y\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1}{x^{2}+1}-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{y}{x^{2}+y^{2}}\right]\\
&=\int_{1}^{b}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{4\left(y-1\right)}{y^{2}-1}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1}{x^{2}+1}\\
&=4\pi\int_{1}^{b}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{1}{y+1}\\
&=4\pi\left[\ln{\left(b+1\right)}-\ln{\left(2\right)}\right],\\
\end{align}$$

and hence,

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{J}{\left(a,b\right)}
&=2\pi\left[\ln{\left(a^{2}+\left(b+1\right)^{2}\right)}-2\ln{\left(b+1\right)}\right]+\mathcal{J}{\left(0,b\right)}\\
&=2\pi\left[\ln{\left(a^{2}+\left(b+1\right)^{2}\right)}-2\ln{\left(b+1\right)}\right]+4\pi\left[\ln{\left(b+1\right)}-\ln{\left(2\right)}\right]\\
&=2\pi\left[\ln{\left(a^{2}+\left(b+1\right)^{2}\right)}-2\ln{\left(2\right)}\right]\\
&=2\pi\ln{\left(\frac{a^{2}+\left(b+1\right)^{2}}{4}\right)}.\\
\end{align}$$

---

Comment: WOW!!! Congratulations! I am very happy with this solution! Thank you a lot for so much work you have done!